# How to get the value of a checkbox in WebGrid

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox, webgrid

I added a checkbox to my WebGrid using

```
grid.Column(format: @<text><input name="chkID" type="checkbox" value="@item.id" /></text>)
```

I couldn't figure out how to access the value of the checkbox to find out which rows are selected.

Is there something like

```
Model.ToList().Where(i.Checked)Select(i => i.id)))?
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, your checkboxes have name attribute values set? If so, just check the Request.Form collection to see which ones have been checked.

Comment: the checkbox is a column of a webgrid, created using:grid.Column(format: @<text><input name="ID" type="checkbox" value="@item.id" /></text>). Could you please explain how to access it using Request.Form? Thanks.

Comment: Request["ID"] will give you a value, or a series of comma separated values if more than one row is selected.